# Block an element by name only on a specific website using uBlock (or Adblock Plus)

Tags: adblock, ublock

A website I have visited has a very large div at the top, normally containing ads.  uBlock has stopped the ads from appearing, but because they were within an otherwise innocuous div, the huge empty space is still showing.  When using the element picker, I can effectively block the div by name.  However, the name is simply `leaderboard` which seems like it might be common enough to show up on other websites, so I want to limit it to the specific domain.

The originally generated filter rule is `###leaderboard`, and it does work.  Following the [filter rules suggested here](https://adblockplus.org/en/filter-cheatsheet), I thought to be able to block it on this site only by modifying it like so `example.com##leaderboard` but this fails to block anything.  I've tried a few variations on that as well, but still found nothing useful.  I have also tried all the variations in Adblock Plus, just to make sure it wasn't a quirk in uBlock's implementation of the Adblock filter rules.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: For one site, consider greasemonkey. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373265/how-do-i-restrict-chrome-greasemonkey-scripts-to-a-single-webpage-or-just-certa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter `example.com##leaderboard` would hide an element `<leaderboard>` on the domain `example.com` which is not useful since there is no such element. What you want instead is the filter `example.com###leaderboard` because `##` is separating the domain `example.com` and the [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) `#leaderboard`.

Note that the documentation you're referring to is incomplete and out-of-date. You can find the official filter syntax documentation at [adblockplus.org/filters](https://adblockplus.org/filters).

Comment: That makes sense, and it did work.  I swear that it was one of the permutations I tried before asking here, but oh well...